# What Authorization header type should be used to send new JWT authentication tokens?

Tags: http, authentication, types, header, authorization

I am building a RESTful API and I'm using JWTs for the authentication. I need to occasionally send back authentication tokens, and I would like to avoid sending JWTs back and forth in JSON. I would rather have the front-end negotiate authorization through headers in order to avoid cluttering my requests.

When the front end sends a token, the type is `Bearer`...

```
Authorization: Bearer [JWT Token]
```

But I can't seem to find what the server's type should be when it's providing the token to the client...

```
Authorization: [What Goes Here?] [JWT Token]
```

What should the type of that header be?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom angular http service that inject's the jwt token on every request.

Something like this

```
import {
  Http,
  ConnectionBackend,
  Headers,
  Request,
  RequestOptions,
  RequestOptionsArgs,
  Response,
  RequestMethod,
} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';

import { SecurityService } from './security.service';
import { CookieService } from '../cookie';

/**
 * Custom Http client that handles conversions to json, adds CSRF token, and jwt token and redirects to signin if token is missing
 */
export class SecureHttp extends Http {

  constructor(
    backend: ConnectionBackend,
    defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
    private securityService: SecurityService,
    private cookieService: CookieService
  ) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    if (typeof url === 'string') {
      return this.get(url, options); // Recursion: transform url from String to Request
    }

    return this.sendRequest(url, options);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Get, url: url, body: '' }, options);
  }

  post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Post, url: url, body: body }, options);
  }

  put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Put, url: url, body: body }, options);
  }

  delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Delete, url: url, body: '' }, options);
  }

  patch(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Patch, url: url, body: body }, options);
  }

  head(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    return this.sendRequest({ method: RequestMethod.Head, url: url, body: '' }, options);
  }

  private sendRequest(requestOptionsArgs: RequestOptionsArgs, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {

    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions(requestOptionsArgs);

    // Convert body to stringified json if it's not a string already
    if (typeof requestOptions.body === 'string') {
      requestOptions.body = JSON.stringify(requestOptions.body);
    }

    // Get xsrf token from spring security cookie
    const csrfToken: string = this.cookieService.get('XSRF-TOKEN');

    let baseOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
      })
    });

    // securityService.accessToken returns an Observable with a JWT token
    return this.securityService.accessToken$.mergeMap(token => {

      // If there is a token we add it to the baseOptions
      if (token) {
        baseOptions.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
      }

      // We create a request from the passed in method, url, body and merge our base options in there
      let request = new Request(baseOptions.merge(requestOptions));

      return super.request(request, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.errorHandler);
    });
  }

  private errorHandler(errorResponse: Response): Observable<any> | ErrorObservable<any> {
    if (errorResponse.status === 401) {
      console.log('redirecting to login');
      window.location.href = '/login';
      return Observable.empty();
    }

    console.error(errorResponse);

    return Observable.throw(errorResponse.text().length > 0 ? errorResponse.json() : { status: 'error' });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew about that. I know how to do that. I want to know what type the Authorization header should be on the response.

Comment: You usually get the token in à normal HTTP get and then store it in local storage or a cookie. There isn't a special header for that what I know of.